# Value initialization of nested classes

Tags: c++, c++11, value-initialization

By the rules of value initialization. Value initialization occurs:

> 1,5) when a nameless temporary object is created with the initializer
>   consisting of an empty pair of parentheses or braces (since C++11);
>
> 2,6) when an object with dynamic storage duration is created by a
>   new-expression with the initializer consisting of an empty pair of
>   parentheses or braces (since C++11);
>
> 3,7) when a non-static data
>   member or a base class is initialized using a member initializer with
>   an empty pair of parentheses or braces (since C++11);
>
> 4) when a named
>   variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) is declared with the
>   initializer consisting of a pair of braces.

Trivial example

```
struct A{
    int i;
    string s;
    A(){};
};

A a{} 
cout << a.i << endl // default initialized value
```

without explicitly declared constructor and left with defaulted default ctor // compiler generated one we get.

```
struct A{
    int i;
    string s;

};
A a{};
cout << a.i << endl // zero-initialized value
```

However using antoher struct.

```
struct A{
    int i;
    string s;

};

struct B{
    A a;
    int c;
};

B a{};
cout << a.a.i << endl // default initialized , even tho we did not , int struct B , declared A a{}.
```

The value of a.i is zero-initialized, even without using {} / () construct, which goes against rules ( if i am not mistaken ).

Using same logic on struct B:

```
struct A{
    int i;
    string s;

};

struct B{
    A a;
    int c;
};

B b;
cout << b.c << endl; // default inicialized
```

We get behavior according to rules.

The last example:

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    A() { } 
};

struct B { A a; }; 

std::cout << B().a.i << endl;
```

B().a.i is also zero-initialized while we explicitly declared constructor and its not deleted.

Why are the these values getting zero-initialized? By rules stated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) they should be default-initialized not zero-initialized.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: The last example is from cppreference ( link ). And its stated its zero-initialized.

Comment: I spoke to soon in my original comment. In the very first example accessing `a.i` is UB. In the second it is aggregate initialization, so it's okay. The third is also aggregate initialization, so it's okay. accessing `b.c` in the fourth example is UB. In the fifth example, accessing `a.i` is okay because of the first rule your cited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the difference between `A` being an aggregate or not.

[dcl.init.aggr] (**Emphasis** mine)

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with **no user-provided constructors** (12.1), no brace-or-equal initializers
>   for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),

So when `A` has no declared constructors, saying `A a{}` has the effect of [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

which will construct each member with an empty initialization list:

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member
>   not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list

So you get `int{}` and `std::string{}` which will value-initialize the integer member to zero.

When you do provide a default constructor, the aggregate property is lost and the `int` member remains uninitialized, so accessing it is considered undefined behavior.

---

To be specific:

This code is undefined behavior when accessing `a.i` because you provided a user-defined constructor, so the `int i` field remains uninitialized after construction:

```
struct A{
    int i;
    string s;
    A(){};
};

A a{} ;
cout << a.i << endl;
```

And this code exhibits undefined behavior when accessing `b.c` because you did not perform list initialization on `B b`:

```
struct B{
    A a;
    int c;
};

B b;
cout << b.c << endl;
```

All the other code is okay, and will zero-initialize the integer fields. In the scenarios where you are using braces `{}`, you are performing *aggregate-initialization*.

The last example is a little tricky because you're performing *value-initialization*. Since `B` is an aggregate, it gets **zero-initialized** ([dcl.init]), in which:

> each base-class
>   subobject is zero-initialized

So again you're okay accessing the integer member of the `A` subobject.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it doesn't matter if `A` has a `std::string` as member or not. Either way, it is still an aggregate (no constructors, private/protected variables, no base classes, no virtual functions). I realize OP has edited their question :/ Well, just an FYI.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Thanks. I should've double checked on that. I thought that having a non-aggregate member disqualified it from being an aggregate itself. (This is only true for PODs) I updated the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the rules of aggregate initialization, the members are indeed value initialized.

> **Value initialization:**
>
> *In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an aggregate type, **aggregate-initialization** is performed instead of value-initialization.*

> *The effects of aggregate initialization are:*
>
> 8. ***If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members and bases (since C++17) or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members and bases (since C++17) are initialized by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14) by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates).** If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.*